# AWS Lambda async/await boilerplate

Tags: async-await, aws-lambda

Is there an example how to completely use async/await in aws lambda functions? Most lambda example starts with:

```
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
```

Now I tried to use:

```
module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
```

but now I have to call a lambda-function in this lambda function.

Can I just write:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
  region: 'my-region'
});
let params = {
  FunctionName: process.env.lambdafunc, /* required */
  Payload: "",
  InvocationType: "Event"
};

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {

  /** HERE COMES SOME CODE AND BUSINESS LOGIC  
   * ...
   * ...
  */

  params.Payload = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(MYJSONDATA));

  data = await lambda.invokeAsync(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  });

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      data: data
    }),
  };
};
```

Comment: Your code will call the other Lambda function as you expect it to be but the `data` that you'll get may not be what you want. Invoking Lambdas asynchronously will not return that Lambda's response to the invoking Lambda.

Comment: okay - @dashmug is there a way to do so?

Comment: Yes. Invoke the other Lambda _synchronously_ through `lambda.invoke()` not `lambda.invokeAsync()`.

Comment: :) scrolling in the documentaion ... solves most of the problems :D

Comment: Does that answer your question?